# What does Socket.IO abbreviation io stand for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to socket.IO and wondering what some abbreviation stand for. What does the `IO` **inside the code** stand for? What is actually stored in it? What is `io.socket`s storing?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('message', function(message){

    handler[message.request](message.text, socket, io);
});


socket.on('disconnect', function(){

    handler['disconnect'](socket, io);

});
});
```

Comment: The "word" "io" presumably stands for "input/output". In your code `io` and `io.sockets` are objects which have properties holding other objects or functions.

Comment: I don't know, no API documentation seems to exist. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363466/socket-io-documentation. You can use `Object.keys(io)` and `Object.keys(io.socket)` to have a look at yourself.

Comment: In object oriented languages, everything (almost) is broken down into classes and objects; and these objects have properties and methods that are associated with their type. Check out the link given by @FelixKling

Answer (score 3):

Input/Output

It isn't storing, it is sending and listening.

Answer (score 3):

It stands for input and output. Its taking in input and giving certain output based on the input